# JQuery event handler when select element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Is there an event handler to use in JQuery when a DOM **select** element has finished loading?
This is what I want to achieve. It is working with other events except 'load'.

This piece of code is loaded in the head.

```
$(document).on('load', 'select', function(){
    var currentSelectVal = $(this).val();
    alert(currentSelectVal);
    } );
```

The question was badly formed earlier. I need to attach the event handler to all **select** elements, both present when the document is loaded and dynamically created later.

They are loaded from a JQuery Post to a php-page. Similar to this:

```
$.post("./user_functions.php", 
{reason: "get_users", userID: uID}) 
.done(function(data) { $("#userSelector").html(data);
 });
```

Comment: Is this input loaded on document load?

Comment: When it's loaded? Like, there is the dom load? what do you mean, when select is loaded? You mean changed?

Comment: Tell us *how* they are dynamically loaded. AJAX? Show the script here.

Comment: Edited and explained. Hope my question gets clearer.

Comment: I think I fully answered all of your question. Let me know if there's more I can explain. The links I included should also prove beneficial. Good Luck!

Comment: Read some of your comments and added more to my answer. I think it's exactly what you're looking for. Some way to check select after an Ajax Post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think we're all confused. But a quick break down of your options.
<sub>After an update made to the Question, it looks like the answer you might seek is my last example. Please consider all other information as well though, as it might help you determine a better process for your "End Goal".</sub>

First, You have the DOM Load event as pointed out in another answer. This will trigger when the page is finished loading and should always be your first call in HEAD JavaScript.  to learn more, please see [this API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

### Example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('select').val());
})
/*  |OR|    */
$(function() {
    alert($('select').val());
})
```

Then you have Events you can attach to the Select Element, such as "change", "keyup", "keydown", etc... The usual event bindings are on "change" and "keyup" as these 2 are the most common end events taking action in which the user expects "change".  To learn more please read about jQuery's [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (out-dated ver 1.6 and below only), [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/), and [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

### Example

```
$(document).on('change keyup', 'select', function(e) {
    var currentSelectVal = $(this).val();
    alert(currentSelectVal);
})
```

Now `delegating` the change event to the document is not *"necessary*", however, it can really save headache down the road. Delegating allow future Elements (stuff not loaded on DOM Load event), that meet the Selector qualifications (exp. 'select', '#elementID', or '.element-class') to automatically have these event methods assigned to them.

However, if you know this is not going to be an issue, then you can use event names as jQuery Element Object Methods with a little shorter code.

### Example

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
    var currentSelectVal = $(this).val();
    alert(currentSelectVal);
})
```

On a final note, there is also the "success" and "complete" events that take place during some Ajax call. All jQuery Ajax methods have these 2 events in one way or another. These events allow you to perform action after the Ajax call is complete.

For example, if you wanted to get the value of a select box AFTER and Ajax call was made.

### Example

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.mysite.com/ajax.php',
    succuess: function(data) {
        alert($("select#MyID").val());
    }
})
/*  |OR|    */
$.post("example.php", function() { alert("success"); })
.done(function() { alert($("select#MyID").val()); })
/*  |OR|    */
$("#element").load("example.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
    alert($("select#MyID").val());
});
```

More reading:

- [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.load/)
- [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Something else to keep in mind, all jQuery Ajax methods (like .get, .post) are just shorthand versions of `$.ajax({ /* options|callbacks */ })`!

Comment: Thanks for taking you time. And I might be the most confused here. I fully understand what you say, but my original problem remains: I want the browser to do some task whenever a *select* element is dynamically loaded. Not when the entire document is first loaded. And $(document).ready() will only fire when the document first loads.

Comment: @Einar Not sure if you saw this answer before or after, but that's why I updated the end of my answer. I talk exactly about making changes after a "POST" or "GET" of some sort. What you need to look at is jQuery's success functions on their Ajax methods.

Comment: You comment loaed while I was writing. I might need to do some more reading on those functions. But I realised that elements that are not registered for event handlers before they are loaded is not accesible through any ordinary Javascript DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Einar true. Which is why I said to look at `success` calls. By the time a succes callback function fires, all new elements have been loaded, and, because it's "success", obviously you had no error retrieving some relevant data. Therefor, you shouldn't have any trouble getting the value of a "present" select box, even if it was just added via a `.load` or even in your callback function. Keep in mind, if the select is being "changed" but already exist, then you could use my second example, but it sounds like you're not changing anything maybe? Don't forget, jQuery ajax also has "before submit"

Comment: @Einar I should have also mentioned, and I just added this to my answer, but, "Something else to keep in mind, all jQuery Ajax methods (like .get, .post) are just shorthand versions of `$.ajax({ /* options|callbacks */ })`!"

Comment: Thank you again. That last example did it after some minor tweeking. I dont do much webprogramming so Im sorry if I confused you all with not knowing too much of the vocabulary.

Comment: You answered the s**t out of that question

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //Loaded...
});
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The question was badly fored. I need to attach the event handler to all select elements, also the ones that are dynamically loaded. I will edit my question.

Comment: *How* are they dynamically loaded?

Comment: They are mostly loaded from a jquery Post to a php-page. Like this: 
`$.post("./user_functions.php",
{reason: "get_users", userID: uID})
.done(function(data) {
     $("#userSelector").html(data);});`

Answer (score 1):

For your dynamic `select`s you can put the alert in the callback.

In your `.post()` callback function, try this:

```
.done(function(data) {
    data = $(data);
    alert(data.find("select").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, correct me if I understand this wrong. So you want to do something with the selects when the document is loaded and also after you get some fresh data via an ajax call. Here is how you could accomplish this.

First do it when the document loads, so,

```
<script>
//This is the function that does what you want to do with the select lists
function alterSelects(){
 //Your code here
}
  $(function(){
      $("select").each(function(){
           alterSelects();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Now everytime you have an ajax request the ajaxSend and ajaxComplete functions are called. So, add this after the above:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    alterSelects();
});
```

The above code will fire as soon as the request is complete. But I think you probably want to do it after you do something with the results you get back from the ajax call. You'll have to do it in your $.post like this:

```
$.post("yourLink", "parameters to send", function(result){
    // Do your stuff here
    alterSelects();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your select elements are dynamically loaded, why not add the event handler after you process the response?

e.g. for ajax

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(response) {
   //do stuff 
   //add the select elements from response to the DOM 
   //addMyEventHandlerForNewSelect();

   //or

   //select the new select elements from response
   //add event handling on selected new elements
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: That way it will only work if the elements are present in the original DOM. Not if they are added afterwards.

Comment: For elements that are already on the DOM (on load of a page), you can use
`$(document).ready(function() {
  //on change event, for example
  $('.mySelectDOMselector').on('change', function() {
    doMyEvent();
  })
})`

For dynamically loaded elements, you can add the assignment of the event handler on the success callback of your ajax-post call.

Comment: I know. And my original question was if there is such and event handler that fires when the element is loaded dynamically, not on change or on mouseover. But I might have formed it a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all Selects to be checked when the User-Select is loaded, or just the User-Select?...

```
$.post("./user_functions.php", {reason: "get_users", userID: uID}).done(function(data) {  
    $("#userSelector").html(data);
    //Then this:
    var currentSelectVal = $("#userSelector").val();
    alert(currentSelectVal);
});
```

Comment: Basically only the #userSelector. But that is not a big issue right now. As long as I can fire an event when any of them are loaded I will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little similar to the posters above but to use the observer (pubsub) pattern. You can google for various pub sub libraries out there or you could use jQuery's custom events. The idea is to subscribe to a topic / custom event and run the function that attach the event. Of course, it will be best to filter out those elements that have been initialize before. I havent test the following codes but hopefully you get the idea.

```
function attachEventsToSelect(html) {
    if (!html) { // html is undefined, we loop through the entire DOM we have currently
        $('select').doSomething();
    } else {
        $(html).find('select').doSomething(); // Only apply to the newly added HTML DOM
    }
}

$(window).on('HTML.Inserted', attachEventsToSelect);

// On your ajax call
$.ajax({
    success: function(htmlResponse) {
        $(window).trigger('HTML.Inserted', htmlResponse);
    }
});

// On your DOM ready event
$(function() {
    $(window).trigger('HTML.Inserted'); // For the current set of HTML
});
```